# Count the number of integers in C

Tags: c, count, integer

so I want to create a code that finds the quantity of numbers in a number. So this may sound weird, but it works something like this.

```
Input
12893012

Output
1 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

So the output means that in 12893012, there is one 0, two 1's, two 2's, one 3, no 4, no 5, no 6, no 7, one 8, and one 9.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
 {
 int n,count=0;
printf("Enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
while(n!=0)
{
  n/=10;             /* n=n/10 */
  ++count;
 }
printf("Number of digits: %d",count);
}
```

My code only seems to find the number of digits in the number, any ideas? Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: Dumb solution: `int numberOfZeros = 0, numberOfOnes = 0, numberOfTwos = 0, …;`. Increment them according to the current last digit. Less dumb solution: `int digitCount[10] = {0};`. Increment according to the current last  digit.

Comment: If input was `0`, should output be `1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` or `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` ?

Comment: The posted code contains nothing to count the number of occurrences of each magnitude of digit,  All the posted code does is count the number of digits in the number.   Please post code that tries to answer the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Put it in an array and count.

Roughly,

```
int count[10] = {0};
while(n != 0)
{
  count[n % 10]++;
  n /= 10;
}
```

Print out the result.

Answer (score 2):

You keep incrementing `count` but without checking the digit. This will just give you the number of digits. You need an array in which you can store the count for each digit.

```
int digitCounts[10];
//...
while (n != 0){
    digitCounts[n % 10]++;
    n /= 10;
}
```

You can use `mod` (`%`) to make it easier, because `% 10` gives the last digit.

Answer (score 2):

Make an array that stores the digit count. Remainder operator will give you the last digit which will be between 0 and 9.

```
int digit[10];
//...
while(n!=0)
{
    int d = n % 10;
    digit[d]++
//...
```

And then print it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating an array (or 10 variables) which hold quantitiy of digits, then reading digits one by one and checking what digit it is.
You can read single digit using

```
 scanf(%1d, &variableName)
```

or

```
 getchar()
```

functions.

Answer (score 0):

all thanks go to @rohit89,@this and @Arc676

this is just a correction when zero (0) is entered

```
int count[10] = {0};
if(n){
   while(n != 0)
   {
      count[n % 10]++;
      n /= 10;
   }
}else
   count[0]=1;
```

Comment: If code used a `do { } while` loop rather than `while {}`, the `if()` can be dropped.

Comment: @chux, how?, i can not get the image.

Comment: instead of `if (n) { ...  } else {...}`, use `do { count[n % 10]++;  n /= 10;} while (n);`

Comment: @chux, you are right. that is the best answer, why you didn't post it?

Comment: Too close to yours - hence I suggested for your answer.  Also OP has not answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805418/count-the-number-of-integers-in-c/33805965?noredirect=1#comment55386466_33805418

Comment: @chux, i will not post your idea, all ideas here are too close to each other.